# react-native-maps support offline google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, react-native, offline-mode

I am new to react-native, and I am going to develop an application by using  third-party library called  react-native-maps. Currently, everything just working find with online map as this third-party library is used google map. But my problem is went I move to offline mode it would be caused a problem for my application.

My question is there any possible way to make google maps downloaded/cached when the application is load with the specific bound area of a country?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is not a way to use the react-native provided MapView to cache the map data. At this time the only offline react-native module that supports offline mapping is [react-native-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl). I have used it in one of my projects and it is fairly simple to get up and running. The biggest issue with this project is it is still very pre v1.0 in terms of bugs. For basic cases it gets the job done.

Another project I have found has a lot of great features and has a snapshot function that I think could be used to mimic an offline map. I have not tried this but I am evaluating it at this time. [react-native-maps](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You use two links, this is discouraged in general because links can go dead. Is it possible to add related content to your answer?

Comment: @JFunk The OP referenced the same library you mentioned, `react-native-maps`.

Answer (score 1):

It would function as such:

1. The app can set aside a cache of a maximum size.
2. As the app requests tiles, these are cached to local storage.
3. There is an interface on the map object that enables you to cache a particular tile in the map at a particular zoom level.
4. The app periodically scans the cache and deletes items in LRU order until it gets under the maximum cache size.

Let me know if the maintainers would accept a pull request like this and I can work on it.